# How would I implement Pan & Zoom in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am currently trying to implement a pan & zoom feature using Angular.

I have an image of a map, that I would like to be able to zoom in and out of, as well as pan around with vertical and horizontal scrolling. Zooming I would like to do with a held down shift key and scrolling with that.

What I am struggling with is the transform-origin. Beneath is the code I've used so far but unfortunately this only works when the `transform-origin` is set to `0% 0%`. I would like to zoom in on the point of the image the cursor is currently at, however if I move the `transform-origin` to something else other than `0% 0%`, portions of the image get cut off.

[Here is the project on stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/panzoom?file=src/app/app.component.html) Hold down alt and scroll to see the problem in action.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
  <img src="assets/map.jpg" style="transform: scale({{ zoom }}); transform-origin: 0% 0%;">
</div>
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You can simply use leaflet library to create interactive maps

Comment: I've been thinking about that but leaflet adds a lot of complexity to my project where the only thing I need is panning and zooming. I would like to keep this as small as possible so I am trying to avoid such complex libraries. It's a great thought though and if I can't figure out another way, I might need to use leaflet anyways. Thanks!